# ExpressJS/Mongoose two-way model communication

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, mongoose

Say I have a `User` model and a `Book` model in my express app which both refer to each other - how can I use mongoose middleware to keep both models synced when saving either model?

I think it would be nice if I could use the following structure, so that when the name of a `Book` is modified it's also updated on its author, the `User`, and vice versa.

The problem then of course is that the `User` model is referencing the `Book` model and the `Book` model is referencing the `User` model - a circular reference. Is there any way to circumvent this in a neat and conventional way?

**user.model.js**

```
const { mongoose } = require('../db/mongoose');
const Schema = mongoose.Schema;

const Book = require('./book.model.js'); // <--- REFERENCING BOOK

const UserSchema = new Schema({
    name: String,
    books: [
        {
            _id: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
            title: String,
        },
    ],
});

UserSchema.pre('save', function() {
    if (this.isModified('name')) {
        Book.findAndUpdate({
            'author._id': this._id,
        }, {
            // update name of book author
            'author.name': this.name,
        });
    }
});
```

**book.model.js**

```
const { mongoose } = require('../db/mongoose');
const Schema = mongoose.Schema;

const User = require('./user.model.js'); // <--- REFERENCING USER

BookSchema = new Schema({
    title: String,
    author: {
        _id: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        name: String,
    },
});

BookSchema.pre('save', function() {
    if (this.isModified('title')) {
        User.findByIdAndUpdate(this.author._id, {
            // update the book title
            ...
        });
    }
});
```

Comment: use populate whenever you require. ( http://mongoosejs.com/docs/populate.html )

Comment: Well, I'd want to denormalize my data so that mongoose doesn't have to run a database query each time it needs the title/name. So I would rather avoid using populate.

Answer (score 0):

My suggestion would be to actually create an association-collection `UserBook` which you'll reference from both `User` and `Book` collections.

`UserBook` will contain two fields, one for the id of the *book* and the other for the id of the *user*.

As for the updates: you'll start by updating the association-collection and then propagate from it to both collections. Say you want, for example, to update a book, what you'll actually do is update the `UserBook` collection which you'll design in a why to launch updates, something like this:

[image]

Comment: I can see that it *could* work. It just seems a bit odd. Is this a conventional solution? I have not seen it being used elsewhere. Maybe have I misunderstood the utility of mongoose middlewares to begin with?

Comment: This is actually an old trick from relational databases design (and really any database design), I would imagine it can be usefull in this type of situations. Maybe you'll get better help by sharing the functional/business constraints, in which case it might be the case that you can only keep one reference of the two. Are you getting a stackoverflow exception or are you just seeking better modeling?

Answer (score 0):

The [documentation](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/middleware.html#notes) for middleware/hooks states that:

> Pre and post `save()` hooks are not executed on `update()`, `findOneAndUpdate()`, etc.

Therefore, a call to `book.save();` should not trigger the save-middleware of it's `user`.